# qx.log.appender Syntax

Tags: javascript, frameworks, qooxdoo

When declaring qx.log.appender.Native or qx.log.appender.Console, my IDE (PyCharm) complains about the syntax:

```
// Enable logging in debug variant
if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug"))
{
    qx.log.appender.Native;
    qx.log.appender.Console;
}
```

(as [documented here](http://www.qooxdoo.org/5.0.1/pages/development/logging.html))

The warning I get is

> Expression statement is not assignment or call

Is this preprocessor magic or a feature of JavaScript syntax I'm not aware yet?

Clarification as my question is ambiguous:

I know that this is perfectly fine JavaScript syntax. From the comments I conclude that here's no magic JS behavior that causes the log appenders to be attached, but rather some preprocessor feature?!

But how does this work? Is it an hardcoded handling or is this syntax available for all classes which follow a specific convention?

The hints how to turn off linter warnings are useful, but I rather wanted to know how this "magic" works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although what's there by default is legal code, I find it to be somewhat ugly since it's a "useless statement" (result is ignored), aside from the fact that my editor complains about it too. In my code I always change it to something like this:

```
var appender;

appender = qx.log.appender.Native;
appender = qx.log.appender.Console;
```

Derrell

Comment: Thanks, nice workaround (although I found out how to disable the warning in my IDE, see my reply to @mdziekon's comment).

Now I need to know how this "magic" works behind the scenes. See the update to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

The generator reads your code to determine what classes are required by your application, so that it can produce an optimised application with only the minimum classes.

Those two lines are valid Javascript syntax, and exist in order to create a reference to the two classes so that the generator knows to include them - without them, you wouldn't have any logging in your application.

Another way to create the references is to use the `@use` compiler hint in a class comment, eg:

```
/**
 * @use(qx.log.appender.Native)
 * @use(qx.log.appender.Console)
 */
qx.Class.define("mypackage.Application", {
  extend: qx.application.Standalone,

  members: {
    main: function() {
      this.base(arguments);

      this.debug("Hello world");
    }
  }
});
```

This works just as well and there is no unusual syntax - however, in this version your app will *always* refer to the those log appenders, whereas in the skeleton you are using the references to `qx.log.appender.Native/Console` were surrounded by `if (qx.core.Environment.get("qx.debug")) {...}` which means that in the non-debug, `./generate.py build` version of your app the log appenders would normally be excluded.

Whether you think this is a good thing or not is up to you - personally, these days I ship all applications with the log appenders enabled and working so that if someone has a problem I can look at the logs (you can write your own appender that sends the logs to the server, or just remote control the user's computer)

EDIT: One other detail is that when a class is created, it can have a `defer` function that does extra initialisation - in this case, the generator detects `qx.log.appender.Console` is needed so it makes sure the class is loaded; the class' `defer` method then adds itself as an appender to the Qooxdoo logging system

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid JS syntax, so most likely it's linter's/preprocessor's warning (looks like something similar to ESLint's [`no-unused-expressions`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions)).

---

#### Edit:

For the other part of the question - this syntax most likely uses [`getters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) or (rather unlikely as it is a new feature) [`Proxies`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/get). MDN provides simple examples of how this works under the hood.

Btw: there is no such thing as "native" JS preprocessor. There are compilers like `Babel` or `TypeScript's compiler`, but they are separate projects, not related to the vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: For JetBrains IDEs (IntelliJ, PhpStorm, WebStorm, PyCharm) the so-called "inspection" can be locally turned off:

    //noinspection BadExpressionStatementJS
    qx.log.appender.Native;

Comment: I've edited my answer to your edited question. Next time, it's better to ask another question rather than editing already answered one.